# Why is cache leakage power consumption higher than other hardware units?

Tags: cache, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

Is it correct that caches (SRAM cells) have higher leakage power compared to other hardware units with the same area such as ALU? And if so, why is the case?

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: We'll never know. Here, have an upvote to support the little guys.

Comment: Leakage power?  This is an Electrical Engineering question.  This question should be moved there.

Comment: This is a computer architecture question. Don't know where it should go.

Comment: Should have been posted on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ Probably too late to move it now.